# Codefresh Allure Trend

Tags: testing, allure, codefresh

I am using Allure in code fresh. I followed below documentation to configure.
https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/testing/test-reports/
But I am not able to see the trends in the allure report. Is there any changes I should do to get trends in the report. And also in the unit test reporting step as mentioned in the documentation
I have error line Error during adding allure history to test report, cause: Access Denied. I am thinking this might be the reason. Is there any way to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue to this - [Trend not appearing within Allure report on Codefresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70875948/trend-not-appearing-within-allure-report-on-codefresh)

It turned out that our issue was down to the way we have configured the S3 bucket. We had to slightly change the permissions for the S3 bucket so that it the ability to perform actions on the bucket (Such as listing all the objects within it - Which Codefresh wasn't able to do which is why the history / trend wasn't being generated. This was the permissions we deployed for our S3 bucket.

```
Statement = [
  {
    Action = [
      "s3:*"
    ]
    Effect   = "Allow"
    Resource = "${aws_s3_bucket.our-integration-name.arn}/*"
  },
  {
    Action = [
      "s3:*"
    ]
    Effect   = "Allow"
    Resource = aws_s3_bucket.our-integration-name.arn
  }
]
```