# Trend not appearing within Allure report on Codefresh

Tags: continuous-integration, testng, report, allure, codefresh

**Info** - https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/testing/test-reports/

- `allure-testng v2.17.2`
- `aspectjweaver v1.9.6`

I currently have test reports being generated within our builds on CodeFresh after following the above document. These are currently being generated as expected, however the trend / history is not appearing within the reports. It is important that we see this information within the report so we get a historical view of the status of the running tests.

Within our test framework we are using the following dependancy to generate our Allure reports (https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_testng)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then within our pipeline .yml file we are using the `codefresh/cf-docker-test-reporting` image and step to create the Allure test reports.

```
 generate_report:
   stage: generate_report
   title: Generate test reporting
   image: codefresh/cf-docker-test-reporting
   working_directory: '${{CF_VOLUME_PATH}}/'
   environment:
    - BUCKET_NAME=our-bucket-name
    - CF_STORAGE_INTEGRATION=our-integration-name
```

**Report** (This is after running multiple builds)

[Report without trend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO1Ea.png)

**Errors**

The only indication as this why this might not be working is this error message which is printed out as part of the `generate_report` stage within Codefresh.

```
  Start add allure history to test results
  Error during adding allure history to test report, cause: Access Denied <-
  Report successfully generated to allure-report
  Report generation is finished successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that our issue was down to the way we have configured the S3 bucket. We had to slightly change the permissions for the S3 bucket so that it the ability to perform actions on the bucket (Such as listing all the objects within it - Which Codefresh wasn't able to do which is why the history / trend wasn't being generated. This was the permissions we deployed for our S3 bucket.

```
Statement = [
  {
    Action = [
      "s3:*"
    ]
    Effect   = "Allow"
    Resource = "${aws_s3_bucket.our-integration-name.arn}/*"
  },
  {
    Action = [
      "s3:*"
    ]
    Effect   = "Allow"
    Resource = aws_s3_bucket.our-integration-name.arn
  }
]
```